Change HTML on the fly like a Word Processor
I have to make PDFs editable. So, I am thinking of changing the PDF into HTML code, modifying the HTML, and converting back to PDF. The problem I am facing is editing the HTML on the fly. As I press the enter key in the editor(CKeditor), the texts get overlapped.
I want the whole HTML to shift down as if it were a Word file. Please help me out.
